# How to filter excel data based on color of the cell in python?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, styleframe

I have an excel file with many columns. The data has to be separated based on the colour of the cells specific column.

[image]

For example in the above image, last 3 rows should be extracted in single file based on the color of column A1/A2. Similarly, the first four rows can be extracted in other file based on color of cells in B1/B2.

Is there a better solution than the following code/without using pandas??

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from StyleFrame import StyleFrame, utils
sf = StyleFrame.read_excel('sample_name.xlsx', read_style=True, use_openpyxl_styles=False)

def only_cells_with_red_text(cell):
    return cell if cell.style.font_color in {utils.colors.red, 'FFFF0000'} else np.nan
sf_1 = sf[['A1']]
sf_2 = StyleFrame(sf_1.applymap(only_cells_with_red_text).dropna(axis=(0, 1), how='all'))

df=pd.DataFrame(sf.data_df)
df_2=df.iloc[sf_2.index]
print(df_2)
```

Comment: What's wrong withe the code you gave?

Comment: I have reached the output but it doesn't seem optimum code... Is there a better solution than the above code?? ... maybe purely in style frame